# Django's non-required datetime field validation doesn't act as intended

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, datetime

I have a small Django application with very basic models and forms, where the element that gives me issues is the `DateTimeField`.

Model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    what = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    due = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    #[...]
```

Form:

```
class TaskForm(forms.Form):
    due = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
```

In the view, upon `POST`:

```
form = TaskForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
     # further processing
     # create new task or edit existing task, for example:
     new_task = Task('what':request.POST['what'],
                     'due':request.POST['due'])
     new_task.save()
```

In the template, for the displaying of the `DateTimeField`, I use the [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), which works just fine.

The problem is that I seemingly can't choose the correct format for Django. Form what I've read any of the below formats should be fine.

```
[
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
]
```

But when I choose a DateTime with the DateTimePicker it's not accepted.

I receive a `ValidationError` from Django. From what I can tell, it's not from `.is_valid()`, but from the `.save()` function.

```
['„“ value has an invalid format and must be of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM [: ss [.uuuuuuu]] [TZ]']
```

I can't find the culprit, as it seemingly is `""`. How could I narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, after validating and cleaning the data, you've ignored all of that work and gone straight back to the raw data. Don't do that.

To begin with, you should always access the data after validation from the form's `cleaned_data` dict. This will contain the data that has been correctly converted to the right data types, in this case a datetime.

```
 new_task = Task('what': form.cleaned_data['what'],
                 'due': form.cleaned_data['due'])
```

(You should ensure that your TaskForm contains a `what` field as well.)

But in fact Django makes it easier than that. If you make your form inherit from ModelForm, and add an inner Meta class with `model = Task`, you can simply do `form.save()` and it will create the Task for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I wasn't aware of the  `cleaned_data` attribute, but that actually makes sense.

Comment: With your suggestion everything works as intended, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44516332/1920748) you could also pass the format to the DateTime widget so that it can parse it correctly

```
due = forms.DateTimeField(required=False, 
            widget=forms.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])
#  use whichever formats you want.
#  format is the format needed by the frontend, 
#  & input_formats is a list of possible input formats that need to be parsed
```

Alternatively you could return the format that django is want from the frontend
I believe the bootstrap datetimepicker allows to [pass format as an option](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format). Here is the list of [supported formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) if you need.